# In xcode, how to use angle brackets import with a specified search path?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings

I put some third-party source files in my project's "Third party" folder, and dragged that folder into my project. In xcode build settings, I specified `Header  search paths` to "$(SRCROOT)/Third party/". But xcode still doesn't know where the `#import <pop/POPAnimatableProperty.h>` file is, but it's just in the `Third party/pop/` folder. If I import it like `#import "POPAnimatableProperty.h"` or `#import <../pop/POPAnimatableProperty.h>`, then it can find that file.
It's impossible to manually change all the imports, so how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Try do a next: `"$(SRCROOT)/Third party/**"` - it's means recursively.

Comment: I tried but no use. Xcode still cannot find the file. : (

Comment: Hmm.. That should work. I checked this case in my project. All ok.